# React JS: My page doesn't refresh after my state constant was refresh

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I have an issue because when I'm using my function setEvents to update my state events's value (using my setEvents function), my page isn't refreshing.

Look here :

```
function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const clickDate = (e)=>{
    const newEvents = events
    const event = {
      id: 'test',
      title: 'my event',
      start: e.dateStr
    }
    newEvents.push(event);
    setEvents(newEvents);
    console.log(events);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView='timeGridWeek'
        weekends = {weekEnd}
        selectable = {true}
        allDaySlot = {false}
        eventConstraint = "businessHours"
        dateClick = {clickDate}
        events = {events}

      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My "console.log(events)" display correctly the new events after having used my clickDate function, but the page is not refreshing.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you're mutating state here:

```
newEvents.push(event);
```

Which is kind of hiding in some over-complicated logic for just setting a new state value.  And when you update state, it's to a reference to the same array (that you've now mutated).

Simplify what you're doing.  Update the state to a new array constructed from the elements of the previous one plus the new element:

```
const clickDate = (e)=>{
  setEvents([...events, {
    id: 'test',
    title: 'my event',
    start: e.dateStr
  }]);
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help.  it's working perfectly Have a good time